# Is there a way to turn off query parametrization in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I'm using TypeORM with MS SQL Server.

In TypeORM default set up SQL queries, generated by `.insert` and `.update` methods are compiling in parametrized queries in SQL.

**Is there a way to switch to inlining of data instead of parametrization?**

P.S. I know about possibility of SQL injections in this case, but:

1. my data is validated before being persisted in my code and
2. from tests (we operate with big data sets (5m record with 1 column - integer, 10K records with 30 columns of different data types) that needs to be inserted or based on them, existing rows should be updated) - insert without parametrization works much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this style](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/insert-query-builder.md#raw-sql-support) of inserts:

```
await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(User)
  .values({ 
      firstName: "Timber", 
      lastName: () => "CONCAT('S', 'A', 'W')"
  })
.execute();
```

And as you are aware, you need to escape anything inserted that way to protect against SQL injection.